# Running another artifact after a job

Tags: azure, docker, devops

I've a docker image in a registry for a repo A that I would like to run after a job in the pipelines of repo B. Basically, I have a test repo with test cases that is available as as image in the registry. I want to run this after a deploy if complete in any project via environment variables. How do I achieve this in Azure Devops?

Answer (score 0):

I have addressed this issue by specifying the tag in the docker image and then linking the main job to the test report job. This works now.